# String as an argument to a function pointer

Tags: c

The below program is not taking input in the second iteration of for loop.
Please provide me some solution.

The below program is having function pointers where the string is an input the function pointers.

/******* THE CODE *******/

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define size (100)

int GetName(char *str_Name)
{
    printf("\n Name of the Employee :%s",str_Name);
    return strlen(str_Name);
}

int GetPlaceName(char *str_Name)
{
    printf("\n Name of the Place :%s",str_Name);
    return strlen(str_Name);
}

int GetStateName(char *str_Name)
{
    printf("\n Name of the State :%s",str_Name);
    return strlen(str_Name);
}

int main()
{
    char Names[size] = {'\0'},*Ptr_Names;
    int rtn_len,i;
    int (*char_fun_ptr[])(char *str) = {GetName,GetPlaceName,GetStateName};
    printf("\n First Enter 'Your Name', Then Enter your 'Place Name' and then Enter your 'State Name'");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter the Name : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s",Names);
        Ptr_Names = Names;
        rtn_len = char_fun_ptr[i](Ptr_Names);
        printf("\n Length is :%d",strlen(Names));
        memset(Names,0,size*sizeof(char));
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And, `#include<conio.h>` is bad. And so is `#define size (100)`. Ideally, macros should be Uppercase unless deemed necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: what is the mistake in the above code. I just want to proceed using scanf () function. Please provide me solution.